# How to Retrieve Full Path of a Group with Script Mapper

Tags: keycloak

I created a script mapper under `<my_realm>` --> `Clients` --> `<my_client>` --> `Mappers`.

I am successfully retrieving the names of the groups of an user with:

```
var userGroups = [];
var groups = user.getGroups();
groups.forEach(function (group) {  
  print('---> name:' + group.name);
  userGroups.push(group.getName());  
});
```

Within that realm I created nested groups and joined the child groups with my user:

```
- ParentGroup
--- ChildGroup1
--- ChildGroup2
```

When signing in `userGroups` will be `['ChildGroup1', 'ChildGroup2']`.

How can I adapt the code so that I get the full path `['ParentGroup/ChildGroup1', 'ParentGroup/ChildGroup2']`?

---

Reading through the [docs here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.2/javadocs/org/keycloak/representations/idm/authorization/GroupPolicyRepresentation.GroupDefinition.html) I can see that the `GroupDefinition` has a     `getPath()` method. But `user.getGroups()` returns a [`GroupModel`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.2/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/GroupModel.html) which doesn't have such a method. Explicitly querying the group with `var g = realm.getGroupById(group.getId());` doesn't return a `GroupDefinition`.

How can I access the full path without traversing groups and building the path manually? I am using `Keycloak 16`.